# Databricks wheel file workspace library not installing to cluster

Tags: python, databricks

So, I have a notebook that creates wheel files.
[image]

---

This works fine.
[image]

---

I add a workspace library referencing the `.whl` file. I make sure to copy the file path from the UI.
[image]

---

All is well. However, I can't seem to install it.
[image]
[image]

---

Needless to say, I'm pretty confused. Why isn't this working?

Comment: What Databricks Runtime version is used?

Comment: Azure Databricks Version 13.3 LTS